# There are two ‘=>’, is n’t there only one ‘=>’ in arrow function , what does this mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
const handleChange = name => event => {
setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
};
```

See the complete code at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9ev7e).

Comment: it means a function that returns a function.

Comment: Can I use only one arrow function to receive the parameters "name" and "event" at the same time, and if so, what should I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argumentName => returnValue` is shorthand for `(argumentName) => {return returnValue;}`

So, your code is equivalent to

```
const handleChange = (name) => {
  return (event) => {
    setState({...state, [name]: event.target.checked});
  }
}
```

In other words, `handleChange` is a function which itself returns *another* function, and that inner function does the `setState()` call.

If you did this:

```
const foo = handleChange("Bar");
```

The value of `foo` would essentially be this (a function):

```
foo = (event) => {
  setState({...state, "Bar": event.target.checked});
}
```

Edit: one thing I'll note is that it could be useful to rename `handleChange` to something that more accurately describes what it does. For instance:

```
const createHandleOnChangeFunction = name => event => {
    setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
};
```

Now it's a little more clear what this function does... it creates a function that handles onChange events.

Answer (score 0):

a function that returns a function.

It's like a function factory... where you can build a function where it has ( in this case name ) things preset in the function.

Very common in functional programming.